# How to get my xml file after deployed on azure?

Tags: azure, web-deployment

I have deployed a website on azure currently, which an end users do updates a certain xml file instead of using database.
with that said, I am having problem on these two things:

1. How to get a backup of this specific xml after sometime
2. I am losing some of the data whenever I made a change or commit to the repository.
   Please any one help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Kudu** explorer for accessing files via FTP or doing [bunch](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki) of stuffs on azure based websites. Check out this [link](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Accessing-files-via-ftp) it has all the information you need. If you need quick starter use [this](http://www.thenextdoorgeek.com/post/Quick-ways-to-edit-your-files-hosted-in-Windows-Azure-Web-Sites-(WAWS)-other-than-re-deploying) blog suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid saving anything to the website root folder. Instead, modify your application to save files directly to a blob storage. You can access these files from anywhere anytime. That way it makes possible to create a backup strategy.

**How to use Blob storage from .NET**

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

If you really need to access your website root folder, use Kudu file explorer or FTP to get the files:

```
https://<yoursitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/
```

If you are losing files every commit it's because they are being overwritten by the same files you have on the repository with different content.

Answer (score 0):

As Bruno stated in his answer, a possible solution is to use blob storage for your xml assets. This won't protect you from multiple users accessing the same blob at the same time - you'll still need to deal with the challenge of concurrency. How you do that is up to you (several ways), but you may want to consider queuing your xml-file operations.

Regarding backup: Again assuming you're using blob storage, blobs allow for snapshots to be taken (look at `CloudBlockBlob.CreateSnapshot()`).

Aside from blob storage directly, you can also use a File Share (which ultimately resides in blob storage), allowing for shared content (e.g. SMB share) across your VM instances).